# What package includes AB the Apache Server Benchmarking Tool in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to find [ab - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) for Ubuntu, I'm hoping there's a package I can install for it. I decided I need to do some simple load testing on my applications.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
% sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

The command-not-found package in Ubuntu provides some slick functionality where if you type a command that can't be resolved to an executable (or bash function or whatever) it will query your apt sources and find a package that contains the binary you tried to execute.  So, in this case, I typed `ab` at the command prompt:

```
% ab
The program 'ab' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
bash: ab: command not found
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, my aptitude searches were coming up empty.

Comment: same [instructions for ubuntu 13.10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apachebench-to-do-load-testing-on-an-ubuntu-13-10-vps),  confirmed on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.  See also [`apt-get siege`](https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/)

Answer (score 13):

Another way to search for missing files, e.g. if you use zsh, want to disable command-not-found (slows things down when you misstype commandnames), or are looking for a file that is not an executable:

```
$ sudo aptitude install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file search bin/ab
```